# Inactivity laravel after login

Tags: laravel

Error message:
`The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again.`

After login I get this message. Everything was fine on `localhost`, but after moving project to `shared hosting`, this happened.. There is `crsf_field`, i did clean my `browser history`, in `session.php` `'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120)`... 
Could it be because of different time zones? Because where I am, it's 3pm, but if I echo time in server, it says 1pm..

One of the forms:

```
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <label for="email">El. paštas</label>
                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                    <span class="help-block">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-6 non">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        Prisijungti
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: What session driver are you using, and are you sure it's working?

Comment: 'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'). Well I can see, there are sessions in storage/framework/sessions

Comment: You need to clear config and cache. I am sure, before uploading your files on live server, you  forgot to clear your config and cache data

Comment: I tried to clear now, but the problem is the same..

Comment: I found out that there is Token Mismatch, now trying find out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by sending characters before the laravel response.  There was a breakline and space in bootstrap/app.php before `<?php`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using csrf on your form, It may be cache:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

and if has error again:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Comment: Already tried all of them. It feels like `csrf token` is not created. Although it is in the form, I can see it by inspecting elements. But after submitting the form, it is not stored as a cookie or session value.

Comment: @Agniaa are you sure about using  key:generate? could you please show your form?

Comment: I updated the question. But I should also mention, that all the forms do not work.

Comment: @Agniaa thanks, Have you set SESSION_DOMAIN value? in .env or session.php?and have you tried php artisan cache:config?

Comment: The problem is that csrf token changes after each refresh

Comment: Hey @Agniaa I am sorry for answering late, if your problem is not solved yet. you can contact me on twitter, its id is in my profile

Answer (score 0):

Hope it works for you, you can check your SESSION_DOMAIN within your `.env` file, use empty string as value if you are in localhost, and when you deploy your project to server try to put your actual domain as SESSION_DOMAIN value, e.g

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=yourdomain.com
```

And then clear your config cache using `php artisan cache:clear`, if you don't have CLI access in your shared hosting, try to make this route in your `web.php` and execute it in your browser e.g `yourdomain.com/clear-cache`

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    \Artisan::call('cache:clear');
});
```

Cheers

Comment: I'm sorry sir, I did as you told, but still the same error.. Weird thing that when project was in temporary server everything worked fine, but now in another server I get this mistake.